# android studio emulator issue

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg8Vf.png)

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

Comment: The emulator doesn't support your GPU/GPU driver version.

Comment: any solution???